# Is it possible to load external Style Sheet after Internal styles?

Tags: css

Is it possible to load external Style Sheet after Internal (or embedded) styles get loaded. I mean, say I have a div with **Yellow** background color, set using embedded style in a page, like;

```
<style type="text/css">
div{
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

And can I change the background color to `green` using an external style sheet like;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

If this is possible, show me an example.

I know this is possible with inline style, but I don't want to use that.

Comment: For fun you can always review: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Just put the `<link>` tag after the `<style>` tag, or make the selector in the external stylesheet more specific.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes you can. The styles will be applied in a specific order. See [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) for precedence rules in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to overwrite a css with same class, you can use 'important' in that class. Study more about important in css.

Answer (score -2):

offcourse you can just place the external style sheet after the internal style sheet in HTML **head** section to override the internal style sheet!

**CSS ORDER**

What style will be used when there is more than one style specified for an HTML element?

Generally speaking we can say that all the styles will "cascade" into a new "virtual" style sheet by the following rules, where number four has the highest priority:

**1.** Browser default

**2.** External style sheet

**3.** Internal style sheet (in the head section)

**4.** Inline style (inside an HTML element)

Comment: You are correct about inline styles (however not in the context you are saying. inline styles generally refer to `<element style="" />`...) however the rest is not. Please read : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Just be aware that the style applied to any particular element is not just dependent on the cascading _order_ of the stylesheets. [Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) (part of the cascade) and [inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance) all play a vital role.